# How to customize the python library "Holidays"

Tags: python, database, api

I want to update holidays library by including new local holidays which can be known as similar words and occurs on specific day or range of days. This can be implemented by creating the datekeys list which can store the dates.So I can have default holidays as well as custom holidays

Using the append method of the holidays instance, I tried to include the new holidays of all new events.

```
ind_holidays=holidays.India() 
ind_holidays.append({'22-10-2015':'Dasehra','11-10-2016':'Dasehra','30-09-2017':'Dasehra','19-10-2018':'Dasehra','8-10-2019':'Dasehra','25-10-2020':'Dasehra'})
ind_holidays.append({'11-11-2015':'Diwali','30-10-2016':'Diwali','19-10-2017':'Diwali','7-11-2018':'Diwali','27-10-2019':'Diwali','14-11-2020':'Diwali'})
```

I expect the efficient way of storing the custom events permanently, how to add events over a date interval? 
Thank you

Comment: `over a date interval` - is there a formula to calculate the date each year? Because there is `datetime` module that can operate on dates, so if you know how to calculate the new date, you can use it instead of some manual string operations. :)

Comment: There is no proper formula for calculating date. Can we take the dates from the API directly..